# how to write queries properly inside of a postgres RLS policy

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, row-level-security

I'm trying to do a single implicit JOIN inside of an RLS expression. I get a syntax error and have a "hacky" solution using a subquery, but would love to know if there is a better way.

So assuming two tables, `projects` and `objects`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE app_pub.projects (
  id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4 () NOT NULL,
  owner_id uuid
);

CREATE TABLE app_pub.objects (
  id uuid DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4 () NOT NULL,
  project_id uuid
);
```

The ownership is expressed on the `project.owner_id`, but the policy of interest will check against `objects.project_id`. The procedure `app_pub.get_current_role_ids ()` returns an array of role ids for access.

Specifically this query's boolean result tells us if the user has access:

```sql
SELECT (p.owner_id = ANY (app_pub.get_current_role_ids ()))
    FROM app_pub.projects p, objects o
    WHERE (p.id = o.project_id)
```

I'd like to write a policy like so:

```sql
CREATE POLICY authenticated_can_select_on_objects
ON app_pub.objects
FOR SELECT
TO authenticated
USING (
SELECT (p.owner_id = ANY (app_pub.get_current_role_ids ()))
    FROM app_pub.projects p
    WHERE (p.id = project_id)
);
```

But this obviously fails due to syntax error, hence my question...

So I do have my "hacky" solution is to use a subquery and do `TRUE IN (subquery)`:

```sql
CREATE POLICY authenticated_can_select_on_objects
ON app_pub.objects
FOR SELECT
TO authenticated
USING (
    (TRUE IN (
        SELECT (p.owner_id = ANY (app_pub.get_current_role_ids ()))
            FROM app_pub.projects p
            WHERE (p.id = project_id)
        )    
    )
);
```

And YaY "it works!", with this `TRUE IN (subquery)` which feels wrong. I know I could write a procedure and use that, but was hoping to do something inline in hopes the query planner would be happier.

So, with all that context:

1. is this "hacky" solution the only/best way?
2. can I do a clean select or join like my first attempt was trying to accomplish?

Comment: The query planner is happy with SQL (not PL/pgSQL) functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The USING clause of the CREATE POLICY command expects an *expression* inside the parentheses. An SQL query, by itself, is not an expression, but you can make it into one by writing it as a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES). So you just need another pair of parentheses:

```
CREATE POLICY ..
USING (
  (SELECT p.owner_id = ANY (app_pub.get_current_role_ids ())
   FROM app_pub.projects p
   WHERE p.id = project_id)
);
```

Comment: wow, soooooo simple. Thank you. I honestly wouldn't have thought of that... thank you thank you thank you